# Why does iterating over the properties of the window object causes an error in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I experiences this problem very often and finally thought that it might be worth a question here.

Running the following code in IE, results in the output `frameElement`, which means, that the property frameElement was found but if you try to access it via `window["frameElement"]` it throws an error.

```
for (var i in window){
    try {
        var c = window[i]
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EREGr/)**

I originally realized this problem when i tried to simply access every property of window, but always ended up with an error.

Does anyone know the reason for this? How can it be, that there is a property but that it is not accessible?

Comment: Properties can be enumerable without being get-able.

Comment: Doesn't throw any errors in IE9. 
*Correction* attempt to actually use `c` (e.g. `document.write(c);`) does throw an error

Comment: @YuriyGalanter right now I only have IE10 available but I get the output as described in the question when I run the fiddle.

Comment: @JonathanSampson ok, that's interesting. Is there a way to test if a property is get-able?

Comment: This remark from MSDN doesn't really explain why, but it's a hint: *The window must be a frame or iframe.* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533771(v=vs.85).aspx Apparently MS decided to throw if you try to use it outside a frame/iframe. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.frameElement) doesn't say anything about that, only that the property should be `null` if the current window is not a frame.

Comment: @basilikum You can try to access it; or, if the browser supports it you can try `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'prop')`.

Comment: I think its a security consideration. If an (untrusted) source from within an iframe could get a hold of it's containing element it would be able do to nasty things to the website hosting the iframe.

Comment: @JonathanSampson `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` seems to be supported by IE10 but it returns `undefined` for all the properties of the window object. But for a property of a custom object it works well.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen on any browser.  Properties on any object, including Window, can be getters methods that can have side-effects including throwing exceptions.